# Why do I get Parse error on input`:: here

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a guess the number game.

`

```
main :: IO()

   checkGuess :: (Integral a) => a -> Bool
   checkGuess b = if b == 9 then return True 

main = do
   print "Guess the number?"
   guess <- getLine
   checkGuess guess
```

but I get parse error on input '::' at the function checkGuess

Comment: Due to indentation, possibly?

Comment: Indention where? If i don't indent checkGuess I get parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) instead.

Comment: Not only is your indentation messed up, you also have the type signature of `main` floating way above the body of the function, with a totally different function in between. Not sure what you were trying to achieve with that. Plus your `if` expression is missing an `else` clause (and has a `return` which is definitely an error), and there are at least 2 type errors in the last line of your `main` function.

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson: please do not just indent to get rid of one error, since then likely (like here) another error will pop up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several things that are wrong here:

1. you do not define the function *directly* after you wrote the signature of the function. You thus should first write the signature, and *then* write its binding, strictly speaking this is not an error as [@chi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761601/why-do-i-get-parse-error-on-input-here/57761680?noredirect=1#comment101960191_57761680), but it is nevertheless strongly recommended;
2. In Haskell *indentation* matters: entering and leaving an indentation level says that you start or end a code block, for example for a `where` clause;
3. your `checkGuess` is supposed to return a `Bool`, but with `return True`, you make it a `Monad m => m Bool`;
4. in Haskell an `if ... then ... else ...` without an `else` does *not* exist. That is logical since a function should always return something;
5. `getLine` has as type `IO String`, so `guess` has type `String`, not `Int`, `Integer`, so you can not use `guess` directly to compare with a number; and
6. as [@Krantz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761601/why-do-i-get-parse-error-on-input-here/57761680?noredirect=1#comment102023301_57761680) pointed out, the `print` here should probably be a `putStrLn`, since otherwise we print a string literal, not the string content.

In general it looks like you are writing an *imperative* program in a (pure) function language. A quick fix is the following:

```
checkGuess :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
checkGuess = (9 ==)

main :: IO()
main = do
   putStrLn "Guess the number?"
   guess <- readLn :: IO Int
   print (checkGuess guess)
```

Comment: Thank you! A lot to think about for me :)

Comment: To be pedantic: technically 1) is not an error, but it's very recommended nonetheless.

Comment: Shouldn't we also change the first `print` to `putStr` or `putStrLn`? I believe that `print :: Show a => a -> IO ()` is not intended.